# Pattern identification in a dataset using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
empl_ID day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4  day_5  day_6  day_7  day_8  day_9  day_10
 1        1      1      1      1      1      1      0      1      1      1
 2        0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0
 3        0      1      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1
 4        1      0      1      0      1      1      1      0      1      0
 5        1      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
 6        0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

As we can see we have 6 employees and index 1 indicates their presence for that day. I want to write a code using Python such that I can trace 2 continuous absences i.e. pattern 0 ,0 for day i, day i+1 in a time-frame of 6 days right from the person begins his employment.

For example, employee 1 begins his work at day_1 column, which is his first appearance of 1. So, from columns day_1 to day_6 if we do not observe any continuous 0, 0 that record should be labeled as '0'. Same would be the case for employee 2 (cols: day_3 to day_8), employee 4 (cols: day_1 to day_6) and employee 6 (cols: day_5 to day_10) and they will be labeled as '0'.

However, for employee 3 (cols: day_2 to day_7), employee 6 (cols: day_5 to day_10) they contain a 0, 0 pattern right from their first presence of 1 within the respective time-frame and thus will be labeled as '1'.

It would be really helpful if someone could help me in formulating a code to achieve the above objective. Thanks in advance!

The result should look something like this:

```
empl_ID day_1 day_2 day_3 day_4 day_5 day_6 day_7 day_8 day_9 day_10 label
 1        1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1      0
 2        0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0      0
 3        0     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1      1
 4        1     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     0      0
 5        1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      1
 6        0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with idxmcx and for loop with shift

```
s=df.set_index('empl_ID')
idx=s.columns.get_indexer(s.idxmax(1))
l=[(s.iloc[t, x :y].eq(s.iloc[t, x :y].shift())&s.iloc[t, x :y].eq(0)).any() for t , x ,y in zip(df.index,idx,idx+5)]
df['Label']=l
df
   empl_ID  day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4  ...  day_7  day_8  day_9  day_10  Label
0        1      1      1      1      1  ...      0      1      1       1  False
1        2      0      0      1      1  ...      1      1      1       0  False
2        3      0      1      0      0  ...      1      1      1       1   True
3        4      1      0      1      0  ...      1      0      1       0  False
4        5      1      0      0      1  ...      1      1      1       1   True
5        6      0      0      0      0  ...      1      1      1       1  False
[6 rows x 12 columns]
```